# cakephp 2.1.x - MeioUpload error

Tags: cakephp, meio-upload

Using MeioUpload (https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload) on cake 2.1.x -

Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php 
Plugin:
MeioUpload/
Locale  Model

throwing an error - 
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the MeioUpload plugin
Error: Make sure your plugin MeioUpload is in the app/Plugin directory and was loaded

Model:

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload.MeioUpload' => array(
        'filename' => array(
            'dir' => 'images',
            'create_directory' => true,
            'max_size'=>'10 Mb',
            'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png'),
            'allowed_ext' => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'),
            'thumbsizes' => array(
                'normal' => array('width'=>200, 'height'=>200),
            ),
            'default' => 'default.jpg',
        )
    )
);
```

If I just specify     'MeioUpload' => array(); 
the image isn't uploaded..

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded the plugin? You can do that from the bootstrap file like this.
bootstrap file can be found in `app\Config` directory.

`CakePlugin::load('MeioUpload');`
or
`CakePlugin::loadAll();`